# Specify record type for Opportunity Custom button- Mass edit

Tags: record-type, java, code

I'm not familiar with Javascript at all, but trying to create a button which allows users to mass-edit some key fields of their opportunities. I have the below by copying the code of the preset button of Mass_Edit_Standard_Fields. However, I cannot specify record type. When clicking picklist fields in this mass-edit page, users see all of options not segmented by record type. I'd appreciate if someone help me to add codes into the below for specifying the record type.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A few notes before we get started. Most of the code you have in your button is just fluff. A more practical version of your code can be written as:

```
var ids = {!GetRecordIds($ObjectType.Opportunity)}
if(!ids.length) {
    alert('Please select at least one record.');
} else {
    window.location.href = '/MassManager__MassEdit'+
        '?selectedRecords='+ids.join(',')+
        '&selectedObject=Opportunity'+
        '&selectedFields=Name,AccountId...'+ // Omitted for brevity
        '&retURL'+escape(window.location.href);
}
```

However, getting back to your main question: nothing you do in your button will have any effect on the page you're sending the users to. It's a "managed package," meaning that the package's *provider* has to fix the feature if it's broken. You won't be able to add this feature yourself.